# Force embedded YouTube videos to play at specific quality resolution

Tags: youtube, embed, iframe

Is there a way to force embedded YouTube videos on any site I visit to play at a specific quality?

Specifically I'm trying to have a *Weebl and Bob* marathon, making sure I see every episode by watching it through http://www.weebls-stuff.com/wab (starting at the oldest and clicking "next" after every video), and I'd like every video to play in 720p, but it gets really annoying having to select 720p again in every new episode.

I use Safari 7.0.4, but I'm willing to use Firefox or Chrome if necessary.

To reiterate, this isn't a question about forcing the video quality on a video I've embedded somewhere. That's the question I've found several answers to on Google. I want to know when I have absolutely no administrative control over a website if there's a way to set a default video quality.

Comment: So as the viewer, you want to see embedded videos in a certain resolution, no  matter what the admin of the site posted it at? Do you have cookies enabled? Tested it by setting the first at 720p, all the videos that came after were playing at 720p as well

Comment: There are not enough details and the few details included like the browser name and version are obsolete. Besides updating the web browser and version update the question to clarify if this problem is still occurring nowadays, update details, and show what you have tried like using a web browser with all the extensions disabled in private / incognito mode. Please bear in mind that troubleshooting-like questions are not a good fit for this site as they tend to require a lot of back and forth but this site is not well suited to handle such type of interaction.

Answer (score 0):

YouTube nowadays tries to automatically detect which quality option fits your bandwidth best, and it also stores which quality you prefer in a cookie.

For this to work however, you need to have **third-party cookies enabled** and possibly anything that can interfere – adblockers, privacy enhancing addons, YouTube-altering addons, etc. – disabled.

Comment: oh... well... I wont disable ad-blockers as ads spends my extremely limited daily quota :(, and magic actions helps so much... we have no choice :(

Answer (score 0):

best way is to use an extension to force it - **[https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/iridium/](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/iridium/gbjmgndncjkjfcnpfhgidhbgokofegbl)**

[image]